# The simple extension $\mathbb Q(i+\sqrt{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> I want to
>
> a) show that $i$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are in $\mathbb Q(i+\sqrt{2})$ and that $[\mathbb Q(i+\sqrt{2}):\mathbb Q]=4$
>
> b) find the minimal polynomial of $i+\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Now I can solve both parts easily by first doing b) and show that $x^4+6x+1$ is the sought for polynomial of degree 4, whence $[\mathbb Q(i+\sqrt{2}):\mathbb Q]=4$ follows. Independent of this, the first part of a) is of course easy to verify. But how do I go from there to $[\mathbb Q(i+\sqrt{2}):\mathbb Q]=4$ without going via b)?

Comment: Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(i+\sqrt{2})=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$

Comment: $[{\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{2},i):{\Bbb Q}]=[{\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{2},i):{\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{2})][{\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{2}):{\Bbb Q}]$

Comment: One could show that $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and have $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=2$, as well as $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$. EDIT: as @anon said.

Comment: If you put $\alpha = \operatorname{i}+\sqrt{2}$ then you find that $\alpha^4+6\alpha+1 \neq 0$ and so $x^4+6x+1$ is not the minimal polynomial of $\operatorname{i}+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Right, my bad. The polonomial is of course $x^4-2x^2+9$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way is to see (using what you showed) that $\mathbb Q(i + \sqrt{2}) = \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{2})$ (the inclusion of the right side in the left being obvious, and the opposite inclusion being the first part of (a)).

Now write $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{2})$  as an iterated extension, namely $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})(i).$   The first of these is quadratic, and the second has degree either $1$ of $2$.  But since $i \not\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ (there are many ways to check this, but the easiest is perhaps to observe that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb R,$ while $i \not\in \mathbb R$), its degree must be $2$.  The second part of (a) follows.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've shown that $i$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are elements of your field, we have

$$\Bbb{Q} \leq \Bbb{Q}[i] \leq \Bbb{Q}[i + \sqrt{2}]$$

These are both degree two extensions, so the extension $\Bbb{Q} \leq \Bbb{Q}[i + \sqrt{2}]$  has degree at most $2 \cdot 2 = 4$. It's easy to see that both extensions are proper, so the degree is at least $4$ as well.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. The question, however, only assumes knowledge of $\emph{simple}$ extensions.

Comment: @JohnIsidore I've edited it so that the extensions explicitly are simply.

Answer (score 0):

(i+√2)(i+√2) = 1+2√2i, which means √2i is in the extension field. (subtract 1 and divide by 2, which you can do because this is an extension field of Q).
(√2i)(i+√2)=-√2+2i

(-√2+2i)+(i+√2)= 3i, so i is in the extension field, as is (i+√2)-i = √2,

Comment: Dear Syd, The OP indicated in the question that he was already able to solve the first part of (a).  The issue is to use this to directly conclude that the degree of the extension is $4$.  Regards,